# Trying to duplicate a View without it's parent - Android

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I've got a list of layouts that I use to generate a new Layout.

However the problem is that before adding the list layouts to the new layout, I need to call removeView() as the list layouts are children. Calling this method removes the view from the UI which doesn't look so great.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = null;

        for(LinearLayout cardView : selectedCardIDList){
            viewHeight += cardView.getHeight();
            if(viewHeight < 842){
                ViewGroup viewGroup = ((ViewGroup)cardView.getParent());
                viewGroup.removeView(cardView);
                linearLayout = cardView;
                pdfViewLayout.addView(linearLayout);
                viewGroup.addView(cardView);
            }
}
```

pdfViewLayout is the layout I'm building with the layouts from the list.

I've tried to find a way to duplicate the layout from the list, that way I thought it wouldn't interfere with my UI, however calling `((ViewGroup)linearLayout.getParent()).removeView(linearLayout);`
still removes it from the UI as it's using the same parent.

Is there a way I can make a duplicate without the parent view ?
Thanks

Edit - With my latest attempt I'm getting the "Child already has parent" error again on the `viewGroup.addView(cardView);` line

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way

1. Create an empty view `View duplicateview = new View();`
2. Copy the target view to the new view that you have created `view = "get your target view that you need to duplicate"//your view`
3. thus the view you looking for is duplicated in `duplicateview`.

Comment: I'm getting "a cannot resolve constructor" on `new View()` when it try it this way

Comment: create view `Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));` don't  forgot to set `LayoutParams`

Comment: Still the same issue. The problem isn't creating the duplicate, the problem is that the duplicate still has the originals parent. And it seem whatever I do with the duplicate affects the original as well. For example, Removing the parent on the duplicate also removes it on the original

Comment: kindly check the duplicate is still attached to the parent and also `layparams` is added to target view. then create a new view add this as a child if it adds the problem is in parent not in child.

Comment: If you check my update question I've assigned ,`linearLayout = cardView;`, the duplicate to the original after I've removed parent from the original. At this point neither of the views have a parent. The next line I add the duplicate to the pdfView and all is ok. After that I try and add the original to the original parent but the app crashes because the original now has the view which was assigned to the duplicate.